# How to find the partial derviative of non-independent variables with constraint

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am given the equation $w = zxe^y + xe^z + ye^z$

Then I am asked to find the total differential  of the equation:
$dw = (ze^y+e^z)dx+(zxe^y+e^z)dy+(xe^y+xe^z+ye^z)dz$

now there is also a constraint that holds

$x^2y+y^2x=1$

And here is where things become unclear to me, $x$ is assumed to be the independent variable, we are to find $\frac{∂w} {∂x}$

The solution to the problem explains that we need to find $dy$ with respects to $x$,$y$ and $dx$ for the constraint. This should give us $dy = \frac { 2xy + y^2}{x^2+2xy} dx$

now to solve for $\frac{∂w} {∂x}$,  and the solution shows $dw = (0+e^0)dx+(0+e^0) \frac { 2xy + y^2}{x^2+2xy} dx+(xe^y+xe^z+ye^z)dz$

therefore, according to the solution we get $\frac{∂w} {∂x} = \frac{x^2 + 4xy+ y^2} {x^2 +2xy}$

The solution for some reason sets the variables equal to 0 and then solves for $\frac{∂w} {∂x}$.  I can't understand why we are able to do set variables to 0.  And what does it exactly mean for $x$ to be the independent variable within this equation?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not to minimize $w$ subject to the constraint ?

Comment: i don't think the problem explicitly stated that but here is a link to the question at hand http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/2.-partial-derivatives/part-c-lagrange-multipliers-and-constrained-differentials/session-42-constrained-differentials/MIT18_02SC_pb_42_comb.pdf