# Let $w = zxe^y + xe^z + ye^z$ and $x,\,y$ satisfy $x^2y + y^2x = 1$. Find $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Implicitly differentiating $x^2y + y^2x = 1$ gives us $(2xy+y^2)dx + (x^2+2xy)dy = 0$ and therefore $dy = -\frac{2xy+y^2}{x^2+2xy}dx$. Substitute this into the total differential $dw = (ze^y + e^z)dx + (zxe^y + e^z)dy + (xe^y+xe^z+ye^z)dz$ and we have

\begin{equation}
dw = [(ze^y + e^z)-(zxe^y + e^z)\frac{2xy+y^2}{x^2+2xy}]dx + (xe^y+xe^z+ye^z)dz
\end{equation}

and then we can conclude $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$ is the part that multiplies $dx$. However, the solution I have also sets $z = 0$ and gives $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} = \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+2xy}$. Why is this the case?

Comment: $z=0$ would mean that $xyw = xy(x+y) =1$ but I don't see anything in the problem that would suggest that to be the case

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2608652/find-the-partial-using-differentials?noredirect=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089557/how-to-find-the-partial-derviative-of-non-independent-variables-with-constraint?noredirect=1